# "Protein-coding" or "Protein-encoding"?

Tags: grammar, synonyms

The reason I am asking this is the following. Some time ago I performed proofreading of a book, and there was a phrase containing "Protein-encoding genes". [I wrote a post on my blog](http://forthescience.org/blog/2008/04/19/code-or-encode-this-is-the-problem/), detailing why this is wrong, according to the assumption that "to code" means to write something in a given standard representation (like "I code a program" in the sense that I write a program in a standard representation of a programming language). Another example is [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding), which is an algorithm for compression. To encode, on the other hand, means to transform something into something else, for example, [base32 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32) transforms binary data into text, so it is possible to send it via email.

Now I am not really sure about it anymore. What I can say for sure, is that genes do not perform any operation, they just store information, so to me "Protein-coding genes" makes a lot more sense than "Protein-encoding genes". I don't understand, in particular, the exact grammar of suffixes like "-coding". Is it a verb, an adjective, or something I'm not aware of ?

Comment: I am not quite sure about protein-coding vs. protein-encoding, the more so that I am not a native English speaker. I would like just to mention that genes either **encode** proteins or **code for** them.

Answer (score 2):

The NOAD reports the meaning that *encoding* and *coding* have in biochemistry.

- *encode* (verb): be responsible for producing a substance or behavior;
- *coding* (noun): the process of coding genetically for an amino acid, protein, or characteristic.

*Coding* is generally defined as *the process of assigning a code to something for the purposes of classification or identification*.

Looking for sentences that contains *coding* in the [Corpus of Contemporary American](http://www.americancorpus.org), I find the following sentences:

> A gene is the hereditary unit such as a segment of **DNA coding** for a specific protein. Human beings have about 80,000 genes, and we are more than ninety-nine percent identical in our genetic makeup.

> Moreover, there are large segments of nonfunctional DNA between genes (i.e., between segments with **known coding** or regulatory roles). The existence of introns and other nonfunctional DNA segments makes it impossible to simply read off a DNA sequence and predict an amino acid sequence (even when all regulatory regions are known).

Looking for *encode*, I obtain the following sentences:

> The gene **encodes** a cell-surface protein dubbed CED-1, which resembles the scavenger receptors in people. Whether the protein recognizes phosphatidylserine or another eat-me sign on a worm's apoptotic cells remains a mystery.

> The mammalian proglucagon gene **encodes** three related sequences, glucagon and the glucagon-like peptides 1 and 2 (GLP-1 and GLP-2), of which has an essential role in metabolism. A family of closely related receptors mediates the physiological actions of these hormones.

> Thanks to the efforts of Paul Hebert at the University of Guelph in Canada, a broad consensus has been reached regarding the gene that is the primary focus of this effort: the cytochrome c oxidase subunit1 (CO1) gene **encoded** in the mitochondrial DNA.

Saying it with simple words, *coding* refers to the process, while *encode* refers to the action of doing that process.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding usage, two metrics point towards “***protein-coding gene***” being used more than “protein-***en***coding gene” by a factor of 2 or 3. The two searches I did where a competitive Google Scholar search, and a standard Google search restricted to the `.edu` top-level domain (which should restrict to academic sources of information).

Next, regarding grammar, *-coding* is not a suffix. It is a **noun + gerund compound, used adjectivally**. You are talking about *a gene that codes a protein*, your verb is *code*, your noun is protein, so the compound is *“protein coding”*. You would say, for example, that *protein coding is one of the functions of the gene*. When used adjectivally, you add a hyphen, and say: *this is a protein-coding gene*.